# Faster or better way than looping to find data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I have an array of object of class Person like the below, with `thisRate` first set to `None`:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.thisRate= None
```

I loaded around 21K `Person` objects into an array, `name` not sorted.

Then I loaded another array from data in a file which has data for `thisRate`, about 13K of them, `name` is not sorted as well:

```
person_data = []

# read from file
row['name'] = 'Peter'
row['thisRate'] = '0.12334'

person_data.append(row)
```

Now with these 2 sets of arrays, when the `name` is matched between them, I will assign `thisRate` from `person_data` into `Person.thisRate`.

What I am doing is a loop is like this:

```
for person in persons:
    data = None
    try:
        data = next(personData for personData in person_data
                        if personData['name'] == person.name)
    except StopIteration:
        print("No rate for this person: {}".format(person.name))

    if data:
        person.thisRate = float( data['thisRate'] )
```

This loop

```
data = next(personData for personData in person_data
                if personData['name'] == person.name)
```

is running fine and uses 21 seconds on my machine with Python 2.7.13.

My question is, is there a faster or better way to achieve the same thing with the 2 arrays I have?

Comment: When you say array, do you mean lists?

Comment: yes lists, edited in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Make an dictionary from `name` to `thisRate`:

```
nd = {}

with open(<whatever>) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(<whatever>):
    for row in reader:
        nd[row['name']] = row['thisRate']
```

Now, use this dictionary to do a single pass over your `Person` list:

```
for person in persons:
    thisRate = nd.get(person.name, None)
    person.thisRate = thisRate
    if thisRate is None:
        print("No rate for this person: {}".format(person.name))
```

Dictionaries have a `.get` method which allows you to provide a default value in case the key is not in the `dict`. I used `None` (which is actually what is the default default value) but you can use whatever you want.

This is a linear-time solution. Your solution was quadratic time, because you are essentially doing:

```
for person in persons:
    for data in person_data:
        if data['name'] == person.name:
            person.thisRate = data['thisRate']
            break
    else:
        print("No rate for this person: {}".format(person.name))
```

Just in a fashion that obscures this fundamentally nested for-loop inside of a generator expression (not really a good use-case for a generator expression, you should have just used a for-loop to begin with, then you don't have to deal with `try-catch` a `StopIteration`

Comment: the try-catch is so that person without data will be reported for further action later, like providing the missing rate for this person.

Comment: @StevenYong that can be replaced by an [else-clause in to your for-loop](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Comment: For that matter, `next` + genexpr need not raise `StopIteration`. `next` can be passed the genexpr and a default argument if no hits are found: `next((personData for personData in person_data
                        if personData['name'] == person.name), None)` It's a perfectly valid use case.

Comment: @shadowRanger would you show me an example how please? OK, you just did, thank you!

Comment: @StevenYong Look at how I modified the for-loop with an `if thisRate is None` to see how you can handle the cases where there is no corresponding name...

Comment: @StevenYong: For the record, that use of `next` doesn't really save anything here, it's not going to make your code faster. I was just pointing it out as a note that, if it weren't a case of using the wrong algorithm, `next` would be fine; you don't need to handle it via `StopIteration`.